# Integrating Qunit into client side framework

Tags: qunit

Are there any examples of how Qunit can be implemented into a full scale development cycle. The existing examples seems to require hardcoding test scripts into production source code. Is there currently a way to separate unit tests and source code? I just want unit test code in dev code, not production.

Thanks
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at existing projects using QUnit, e.g. [jQuery UI](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui). The [folder tests/unit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/tests/unit) contains all the QUnit-based unit tests. Is that separate enough?

Comment: For Jquery yes. I have a MV3C asp.net project, http://silk.codeplex.com/ gives example for MVC3 specific.

Answer (score 1):

1) Keep your tests on the dev. environment in a dedicated folder. E.g. like that

```
app-wwwroot/
  ├── js/
  │   └── moduleA.js
  └── tests/
      ├── moduleA/
      │    ├── dummies.js
      │    ├── stubs.js
      │    ├── mocks.js
      │    ├── fixtures.js
      │    └── unit-tests.js
      └── unit-tests.html
```

2) Exclude the folder from your deployment script or production branch in your version control system